# Home directory encryption

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs

I've just encrypted my home directory after installing ubuntu (i.e. my home directory was initially not encrypted then I used the `ecryptfs-utils` to encrypt it).

I am curious to know whether only the current content of home directory would be encrypted or all data saved further will also encrypted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the future files that you save in your home directory will be encrypted as well.

Comment: @green7 Can you provide a source for this information?

Comment: Good question. I've been googling for that but no information !

Comment: I just happen to know it by experience. Also, it is essentially the same as the encryption option offered by Ubuntu when you install it. You don't go about encrypting it again and again. Once it's encrypted, you're done!

Comment: It seems to be logic. However, how can you explain the fact that encryption (when it is done after installing ubuntu) takes as long time as the size of data currently present  in home directory?

Comment: Encryption, in the simplest form, is conversion of some bit pattern to another bit pattern using some standard bit pattern (which is your encryption key). More the number of bits to convert, more time it is going to take. Hence, larger the size of the home directory, more time the encryption process is going to take.

Comment: Yes, that's right. So, encryption depends only on data present in the home directory and that what will be really encrypted not the future data unless the encryption is done on-the-fly before effective writing on HDD. In this case, performance becomes the real issue!

Comment: What is already present in home directory is encrypted when you first run the command, and the future files are encrypted on the fly.